# Mass delete items in DynamoDB

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table called Media, where the primary key is the mediaId. I have an additional table called Media_Comments which has a commentId as the primary key, and a mediaId attribute that stores the mediaId that that comment is linked to. Same with Media_Likes, I have a primary key of mediaId and sort key of userId. I want to handle a case where a Media item is deleted by a user, which will then cause a mass deletion of all comments and likes of that Media item. I am currently writing this code in a lambda using Node.js.

I tried using a regular delete based on the condition of where 'mediaId = :mediaId', but it was complaining about needing a primary key for the table. Unfortunately, many times when I want a media item deleted I won't have specific key items available to fulfill that condition. I looked into trying to delete by a certain index, like setting a GSI on the mediaId in each table and deleting by that, unfortunately that does not seem to be an option either.

Basically, am I missing something? Is there actually a way to delete by an index? And if not, what would be the best way to do this? Setting a TTL for each item in dynamodb that is affiliated with the Media item? Or is there another recommended way to handle this problem?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: DynamoDB is a document database. You're designing your data with relational models. This isn't going to work out for you. There's no way to accomplish what you're trying, the best you can do is to write a background job that removes documents from any auxiliary tables when the `Media` record is deleted

Comment: @CollinDauphinee I'm not sure it's accurate to say that there's "no way" to do this. It's true that cascaded deletions are not an intrinsic feature of DynamoDB so you have to roll your own (in this case perhaps through DynamoDB Streams triggering a Lambda that then applies a TTL to the subordinate records, or outright deletes them, either way using BatchWriteItem). This pattern is better-supported by an RDBMS, for sure.

Comment: @CollinDauphinee, thank you for your insight. Would you recommend something like Aurora Serverless to develop a database like this? For the most part we've basically built a relational database within Dynamo.